# Rendering css style applied React stateless functional statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, stateless

I am trying to render component written in stateless functional component in React.js. when I tried to render code below, the element does not show up. React and React-Dom script files are properly inserted.

```js
const showMe = () => {
  return (
    <div className="hi"></div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(showMe, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```css
#target {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  border:1px solid red;
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
}

.hi {
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  height:40%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Comment: It should be `<showMe />` and you should use capitalized component names like `<ShowMe />`Also, there must be a DOM element with the id `target` in your HTML file.

Comment: Ah, so using capital first letter is part of syntax not only for convenience? thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const ShowMe = () => {
  return (
    <div className="hi"></div>
  )
};

ReactDOM.render(<ShowMe />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

```css
#target {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  border:1px solid red;
  width:600px;
  height:500px;
}

.hi {
  border:1px solid blue;
  position:absolute;
  width:50%;
  height:40%;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ReactDOM.render(< ShowMe />, document.getElementById("target"));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I also tried that syntax, but it does not work still :(

Comment: using capital letter for the first letter of the JSX component was the answer! thank you all!